# How to calculate running total in an Array. PHP

Tags: php

I have an array that for instance looks like this:

```
$cases = array(23, 18, 5, 8, 10, 16);
```

What I want the output to be is a running total:

```
23, 41, 46, 54, 64, 80
```

Some information to help clarify: This array is currently populating a line graph and my goal is to try and add a line that shows the cumulative progress each day. (data is coming from a DB so I cant just change original array)

Comment: On what part are you stuck?

Comment: The php logic to iterate through an array and keep a running total.

Comment: Have you at least tried anything yourself? What was the problem when you tried it? Where were you stuck?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest way, with O(n) complexity:

```
$original = array(23, 18, 5, 8, 10, 16);

$total = array();
$runningSum = 0;

foreach ($original as $number) {
    $runningSum += $number;
    $total[] = $runningSum;
}

var_dump($total);
```

Comment: +1. Textbook example :)

Comment: Clear, simple, and you initialized your variables properly. :) Unless your source list is huge or an open-ended iterator, this is much more efficient than the iterator/generator solutions, both in execution and readability (=efficiency of maintenance)

Comment: Thanks was able to implement this into my code very easily

Answer (score 9):

A little line with `array_map`. It iterates over the array, incrementing the actual total sum and returns it.

```
$actual_sum = 0;
$running_total = array_map(function ($entry) use (&$actual_sum) { return $actual_sum += $entry; }, $cases);
```

Comment: OK hope you had noticed to comments under @PhilCross 's answer. I'm going to delete my answer and also will put my upvote (+1) on your answer. that is also true.

Comment: @imsiso Yeah, I saw them, I just didn't notice the chronological order first; that's why I was confused.

Comment: `$actual_sum` is not defined at the start.

Comment: @Jack Is this a problem? `$undefined_val += $value` won't raise a notice.

Comment: @jack not an issue, as it's declared in the use line, so it is actually defined (and initialized as null, if it wasn't before) in the declaration. It's a weird case, but it works...

Comment: No, it's not a problem; it will work without raising notices ... it's a pedantic thing I guess :)

Comment: Heh, this is why I dislike PHP's choice of when to raise notices - that's exactly the kind of situation where you should always initialize to a starting value of 0; otherwise, if this line ends up inside a loop, you'll get mysteriously high values as the variable gets held over from a previous invocation.

Comment: @IMSoP okay, changed.

Answer (score 4):

Introducing the `RunningTotalIterator` solution, mostly written to complement the other answers:

```
class RunningTotalIterator extends ArrayIterator
{
    private $sum;

    public function rewind()
    {
        parent::rewind();
        $this->sum = $this->valid() ? parent::current() : 0;
    }

    public function current()
    {
        return $this->sum;
    }

    public function next()
    {
        parent::next();
        if ($this->valid()) {
            $this->sum += parent::current();
        }
    }
}

$result = iterator_to_array(new RunningTotalIterator(array(23, 18, 5, 8, 10, 16)));
print_r($result);
```

Comment: You have a potential logic error where rewinding may produce an invalid sum. Instead, set it to `0` prior to the `if $this->valid()` check in rewind() or in an else branch,...

Comment: @ircmaxell That's true, it was intentionally left out because an empty array would yield an empty array ... calling `current()` on an empty iterator isn't defined either afaik ... but I'll change it nonetheless :)

Comment: the edit looks good. But it is possible in the case I modify the iterator (unsetting a value for example)...

Answer (score 4):

Using Generators (a new 5.5 feature):

```
function getRunningTotal(array $array) {
    $generator = function(array $array) {
        $total = 0;
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            $total += $value;
            yield $key => $total;
        }
    };
    return iterator_to_array($generator($array));
}
```

If you wanted to keep the result as an iterator, just return the `$generator($array)` directly...

The way this works, is that the engine internally creates a generator (which acts like an iterator) that "returns" whatever is yielded. So by keeping our own running total inside the function, we can "yield" it back to the caller. Pretty straight forward...

Comment: +1. (@NikiC should have written this) I really like this approach, at least because it's not oversized and portable.

Comment: @bwoebi not oversized, yes (because generators are literally iterator shorteners) ... portable (compared to full blown iterators), arguable unless you mean easier to copy and paste ;-)

Comment: @Jack more portable... ircmaxell has convinced me that we can simply copy paste it, without modifications, if we want to iterate over it, want it as array etc.

Answer (score 3):

`array_sum()` would return the total of all numbers in the array added, however if you want a `running total`, here go:

```
$total = array();
$original = array(23, 18, 5, 8, 10, 16);

foreach($original as $number)
{
    $total[] = array_sum($total)+$number;
}

print_r($total);
```

Comment: Your right... I missed of a closing curly brace.

Comment: My basic maths skills going downhill!

Comment: Unbelievable! Updated, simplified!

Comment: An `$total[] = array_sum($total) + $number;` should be faster and shorter.

Comment: It's much more efficient to just use an intermediate `$sum` variable instead of repeatedly doing `array_sum()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$cases = array(23, 18, 5, 8, 10, 16);
$running = array_reduce(
    $cases,
    function ($counter, $value) {
        static $summer = 0;
        $summer += $value;
        $counter[] = $summer;
        return $counter;
    },
    array()
);

var_dump($running);
```

Comment: oooh, how complicated :o It's possible but really too much instructions for the little task.

Comment: You'd already given a simpler answer, I was merely reminding readers that PHP has a great range of features

Comment: I didn't downvote it as it is not wrong, but it's more abusing the array_reduce function than using another appropriate function here.

Answer (score 2):

Aaaaand another variation with [`array_walk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php), which IMHO is most natural:

```
$cases = array(23, 18, 5, 8, 10, 16);
$totals = array();
array_walk($cases, function($v) use (&$totals) {$totals[] = end($totals) + $v;});
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/WW5yOJ)**.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?
$total = array();
$points = array(23, 18, 5, 8, 10, 16);

while ($points) {
 $total[] = array_shift($points);
 echo 'point: '.array_sum($total);
}
?>
```